# Hierarchal Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: d3.js

I've converted [Mike Botock's Hierarchical Bar Chart](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1283663) to v4 and made some tweaks to fit my needs(vertical, tool-tip, widths of bars fit canvas, etc).

Now I'm trying to make this a stacked bar chart. In my JSON file I have two types of downtime Machine and Die.  For the original chart I just add these up to get my overall but now i want to stack them and I'm unsure how to pull these out separately after doing a root.sum on the Hierarchy. This is my first chart so pardon some of the coding but feel free to correct me on anything. I also could clean some things up with if statements but I'm leaving everything separate as it is easier to troubleshoot. Any thoughts on how to make stacked hierarchical bar chart would be appreciated. Even if it means throwing away this code and starting over.

```
<body>
    <script src="d3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        //canvas variables
        var margin = { top: 30, right: 120, bottom: 300, left: 120 },
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        // scale y on canvas from largest number to 0 
        var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

        var barWidth;
        var barPadding = 5;
        var oldBarWidth = width;
        var depth = 0;

        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
            .range(["steelblue", "#ccc"]);

        var duration = 750,
            delay = 25;

        //attach SVG to body with canvas variables declared above
        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


        var divTooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");

        //attach a rectangle to the entire background for drilling
        svg.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "background")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .on("click", drillUp);

        //append axis to the SVG
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "yaxis");
        svg.append("g")
          .append("line")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .attr("x1", width)
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .attr("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");

        //import JSON file
        d3.json("data/drilljson2.json", function (error, root) {
            if (error) throw error;

            //declare root of the JSON file
            root = d3.hierarchy(root);
            //add all children in hierarchy and get value for all parents 
            root.sum(function (d) { return (+d.DieDowntime + (+d.MachineDowntime)); });
            //scale the 'Y' domain/axis from 0 to root value
            y.domain([0, root.value]).nice();


            //call the drill down function
            drillDown(root, 0);
            drillDown(root.children[3], 3);           
        });

        function drillDown(d, i) {

            if (!d.children) return;

            // get the number of children to parent and calculate barWidth and keep track of depth of drill down.
            numChildNodes = d.children.length;
            barWidth = (width / numChildNodes) - barPadding;
            depth += 1;


            var end = duration + numChildNodes * delay;

            // Mark any currently-displayed bars as exiting.
            var exit = svg.selectAll(".enter")
                .attr("class", "exit");

            // Entering nodes immediately obscure the clicked-on bar, so hide it.
            exit.selectAll("rect").filter(function (p) { return p === d; })
                .style("fill-opacity", 0);

            // Enter the new bars for the clicked-on data.
            // Entering bars are immediately visible.
            var enter = drillDownBars(d)
                .attr("transform", stackDown(i))
                .attr("width", oldBarWidth)
                .style("opacity", 1);



            // Update the y-scale domain.
            y.domain([0, d3.max(d.children, function (d) { return d.value; })]).nice();

            // Have the text fade-in, even though the bars are visible.
            // Color the bars as parents; they will fade to children if appropriate.
            enter.select("text").style("fill-opacity", 0);
            enter.select("rect").style("fill", color(true));




            // Update the y-axis.
            svg.selectAll(".yaxis").transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

            // Transition entering bars to their new position.
            var enterTransition = enter.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .delay(function (d, i) { return i * delay; })
                .style("opacity", 1)
                .attr("transform", function (d, i) { var transBar = (barWidth +barPadding) * i +barPadding; return "translate("+ transBar + ")"; });

            // Transition entering text.
            enterTransition.select("text")
                .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate("+(barWidth/2)+","+((height+5) + 10 * depth)+")rotate(90)" })
                // working   .attr("y", height + 15)
                .style("fill-opacity", 1);

            // Transition entering rects to the new y-scale.
            enterTransition.select("rect")
                .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.value); })
                .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.value); })
                .attr("width",barWidth)
                .style("fill", function (d) { return color(!!d.children); });

            // Transition exiting bars to fade out.
            var exitTransition = exit.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .style("opacity", 0)
                .remove();

           // Transition exiting bars to the new y-scale.
            exitTransition.selectAll("rect")
                .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.value); })
                .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.value); });

            // Rebind the current node to the background.
            svg.select(".background")
                .datum(d)
              .transition()
                .duration(end);

            d.index = i;
            oldBarWidth = barWidth;

        }

        function drillUp(d) {

            if (!d.parent || this.__transition__) return;

            numChildNodes = d.parent.children.length;
            barWidth = (width / numChildNodes) - barPadding;
            depth -= 1;

            var end = duration + d.children.length * delay;

            // Mark any currently-displayed bars as exiting.
            var exit = svg.selectAll(".enter")
                .attr("class", "exit");



            // Enter the new bars for the clicked-on data's parent.
            var enter = drillUpBars(d.parent)
                .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
                    transBarWidth = (barWidth + barPadding) * i + barPadding;
                    return "translate(" + transBarWidth + "," + 0 + ")";
                })
                .style("opacity", 0);

            // Color the bars as appropriate.
            // Exiting nodes will obscure the parent bar, so hide it.
            enter.select("rect")
                .style("fill", function (d) { return color(!!d.children); })
              .filter(function (p) { return p === d; })
                .style("fill-opacity", 0);


            // Update the y-scale domain.
            y.domain([0, d3.max(d.parent.children, function (d) { return d.value; })]).nice();

            // Update the y-axis.
            svg.selectAll(".yaxis").transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

            // Transition entering bars to fade in over the full duration.
            var enterTransition = enter.transition()
                .duration(end)
                .style("opacity", 1);


            // Transition entering rects to the new y-scale.
            // When the entering parent rect is done, make it visible!
            enterTransition.select("rect")
                .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.value); })
                .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.value); })
                .on("end", function (p) { if (p === d) d3.select(this).style("fill-opacity", null); });

            // Transition entering text.
            enterTransition.select("text")
                .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate("+(barWidth/2)+","+((height+5) + 10 * depth)+")rotate(90)" })
                .style("fill-opacity", 1);

            // Transition exiting bars to the parent's position.
            var exitTransition = exit.selectAll("g").transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .delay(function (d, i) { return i * delay; })
                .attr("transform", stackUp(d.index));

            // Transition exiting text to fade out.
            exitTransition.select("text")
                .style("fill-opacity", 0);

            // Transition exiting rects to the new scale and fade to parent color.
            exitTransition.select("rect")
                .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.value); })
                .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.value); })
                .attr("width", barWidth)
                .style("fill", color(true));

            // Remove exiting nodes when the last child has finished transitioning.
            exit.transition()
                .duration(end)
                .remove();
            // Rebind the current parent to the background.
            svg.select(".background")
                .datum(d.parent)
              .transition()
                .duration(end);
            oldBarWidth = barWidth;

        }

        // Creates a set of bars for the given data node, at the specified index.
        function drillUpBars(d) {
            var bar = svg.insert("g")
                .attr("class", "enter")
              .selectAll("g")
                .data(d.children)
              .enter().append("g")
                .style("cursor", function (d) { return !d.children ? null : "pointer"; })
                .on("click", drillDown);

            bar.append("text")
                .attr("dx", ".35em")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + barWidth / 2 + "," + (height + 15) + ") rotate(90)" })
                .text(function (d) { return d.data.name; });

            bar.append("rect")
                .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.value); } )
                .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.value); })
                .attr("width", barWidth)
                .attr("stroke-width", 1)
                .attr("stroke", "white");

            return bar;
        }

        function drillDownBars(d) {            
            var bar = svg.insert("g")
                .attr("class", "enter")
              .selectAll("g")
                .data(d.children)
              .enter().append("g")
                .style("cursor", function (d) { return !d.children ? null : "pointer"; })
                .on("click", drillDown)
                .on("mouseover", mouseover)
                .on("mousemove", function (d) {
                    divTooltip
                        .text(d.data.name +" " + d.value)
                        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 34) + "px")
                        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 30) + "px");
                });

            bar.append("text")
                .attr("dx", ".35em")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + barWidth / 2 + "," + (height + 15 - y(d.value)) + ") rotate(90)" })
                .text(function (d) { return d.data.name; });

            bar.append("rect")
                .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.value); })
                .attr("width", oldBarWidth)
                .attr("stroke-width", 1)
                .attr("stroke", "white");

            return bar;
        }


        //Creates a stack of bars
        function stackDown(i) {
            var x0 = (oldBarWidth + barPadding) * i + barPadding;
            var y0 = height;
            return function (d) {
                y0 -= height - y(d.value);
                var ty = "translate(" + x0 + "," + y0 + ")";
                return ty;
            };
        }

        //
        function stackUp(i) {
            var x0 = barWidth * i + (barPadding * (i + 1));
            var y0 = 0;
            return function (d) {
                var ty = "translate(" + x0 + "," + y0 + ")";
                y0 -= height - y(d.value);
                return ty;
            };
        }

        function mouseover() {
            divTooltip.style("display", "inline");
        }
    </script>
```

Here is a piece of the JSON file which could also use a little cleaning but minor details for now.

```
 {
    "name" : "Down Time",
    "children" : [{
            "name" : "2013",
            "children" : [{
                    "name" : "May 2013",
                    "children" : [{
                            "name" : "21 May 2013",
                            "children" : [{
                                    "name" : "110",
                                    "children" : [{
                                            "MachineDowntime" : ".00000000000000000000",
                                            "DieDowntime" : ".50000000000000000000"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }, {
                                    "name" : "115",
                                    "children" : [{
                                            "MachineDowntime" : "5.23333333333333333300",
                                            "DieDowntime" : ".00000000000000000000"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }, {
                            "name" : "22 May 2013",
                            "children" : [{
                                    "name" : "115",
                                    "children" : [{
                                            "MachineDowntime" : "2.96666666666666666730",
                                            "DieDowntime" : ".00000000000000000000"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }, {
                                    "name" : "110",
                                    "children" : [{
                                            "MachineDowntime" : ".00000000000000000000",
                                            "DieDowntime" : "10.36666666666666667000"
```

Comment: If I split the Data into two separate JSON files does someone have an idea?

Comment: Could you please post you v4 implementation of the hierarchical bar chart?